# Syntax error on token "default", invalid Label

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Can anyone help me with only error which I got when I was converting switch to if-else statements?

This is code where on the default: Eclipse show me error with message "Syntax error on token "default", invalid Label"

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
int id = v.getId();
if (id == R.id.btn_font_style) {

    font.showDialog();
    } 
else if (id == R.id.btn_font_size) {
    break;
    fsize.show();
    default: //I got error here
    break;
}

}
```

This is my old code

```
        @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_font_style:
        font.showDialog();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_font_size:
        fsize.show();
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like the 'default;' and probably the two 'break;' statements are fragments of the original switch. If you still have the code with the switch, you may want to post it here. That will make it easier to identify how your if-else should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, [`default` is a keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html), and it reserved as the default case in `switch` statements.  Because of this, it is invalid as a normal label.

For a label, you must use an identifier that is not a reserved word.  Also, `break;` statements that are outside of switches or loops are not allowed.

You can also add in a `switch` statement, because it looks like there are `break;` statements that look like they belong in a `switch` statement.

Now that I see the original `switch` statement, converting a `default` case from a `switch` statement to a `if` statement means using an `else` to cover the default case that none of the `if` conditions match.  `break;` statements don't make sense in an `if` statement; they can be removed.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btn_font_style) {

        font.showDialog();
    } 
    else if (id == R.id.btn_font_size) {
        // No break
        fsize.show();
    } else {  // old default case
        // Something here
    }
}
```

Because you happen not to have anything in the `default` case, no `else` clause should be present in the corresponding `if` statement.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btn_font_style) {

        font.showDialog();
    } 
    else if (id == R.id.btn_font_size) {
        // No break
        fsize.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added my old code in first post. Can you suggest me how can I modify my new code, because I`m pretty new in programming without skills :(